# Docker fails to find entrypoint script when I copy it to the location which starts with "/home/"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM alpine:3.14

COPY my.sh /home/app/welds/shell_scripts/my.sh
RUN chmod +x /home/app/welds/shell_scripts/my.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/welds/shell_scripts/my.sh"]
```

where `my.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh   
echo 'foo!'
```

I build it `docker build -f Dockerfile . -t test` and run it `docker run test` on local computer with Docker Desktop on MacOs with output:

```
foo!
```

No surprise. Once I deployed it to Azure App Service (Linux for containers) it fails with error:

```
InnerException: Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException, Docker API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"message":"OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: \"/home/app/welds/shell_scripts/my.sh\": stat /home/app/welds/shell_scripts/my.sh: no such file or directory: unknown"}
```

When I change Dockerfile to not use "/home/" like

```
FROM alpine:3.14

COPY my.sh /app/welds/shell_scripts/my.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/welds/shell_scripts/my.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/welds/shell_scripts/my.sh"]
```

it then works both on Azure AppService and localhost.

My target image to be based on is `phusion/passenger-ruby26:2.0.0` I changed it here for alpine for simplicity but it's exactly the same case wile using `phusion/passenger-ruby26:2.0.0`

How it is possible Azure has problem to run container which has entrypoint located at path containg "/home/"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system) and [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/operating-system-functionality#types-of-file-access-granted-to-an-app) I'd say that `/home` is used for Azure related files:

> This is what you can view as your web site's files. They follow a structure described [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure). They are rooted in `%HOME%` directory. For App Service on Linux and Web app for Containers, persistent storage is rooted in `/home`.

> The `%HOME%` directory in an app maps to a content share in Azure Storage dedicated for that app, and its size is defined by your pricing tier. It may include directories such as those for content, error and diagnostic logs, and earlier versions of the app created by source control.

Those file probably are managed by Azure, meaning that anything you put under `/home` would be replaced at runtime.